# Single word request for not liking to be touched

Tags: single-word-requests

Please what is one word for not liking to be touched? It could be for whatever reason (pride, hygiene, hostility, etc.). It includes all touches especially from strangers from taps on the back to pokes. The person not liking the touch may show facial expressions of displeasure, irritation or frustration.

Example:
That king doesn't like being touched. He slapped a peasant for touching him.

Comment: Hi W.Bruce, welcome to EL&U. You might not be aware that there are strict rules for [tag:single-word-requests]: "To ensure your question is not closed as off-topic, please be specific about the intended use of the word. *You must include a sample sentence demonstrating how the word would be used*."  You can add this using the [edit] link. For further guidance, see [ask], and make sure you also take the EL&U **[Tour]** :-)

Comment: I think that the word "touchy" must have meant this but lost its literal meaning and now refers only to one who is easily offended.

Comment: Okay thanks for your response. However, first of all, how does "touchy" mean having a dislike of being touched? What the literal meaning of "touchy" seems to me is rather someone who likes touching. Also, when did this "loss of literal meaning" occur as you claim? Because all meanings I found had to do with being sensitive.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use "***touch aversion***", if it is **not** on extreme side of dislike or fear or aversion. If it is extreme (dislike, fear, or aversion), then it is called **Haphephobia.**

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haphephobia

> Haphephobia is a rare specific phobia that involves the fear of touching or of being touched.

According to Oxford dictionary the word phobia is described as

> An **extreme** or **irrational** *fear* of or *aversion* to something.

If you have ever seen the television sitcom *The Big Bang Theory*, then the character Sheldon Cooper has this fear of touch called Haphephobia.

There are few other closely related "fear of touch": *[Aphenphosmphobia](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/aphenphosmphobia), [Aphephobia](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/aphephobia), [Chiraptophobia](http://common-phobias.com/Chirapto/phobia.htm), and [Haptephobia](http://common-phobias.com/Hapte/phobia.htm).*